# multiple lines in vim tabpage window

Tags: vim

This is not about indentation.

I usually uses vim's [tabpage](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html) to open multiple files.
This usually works well, but when there are too many tabpages, tabpage starts to shorten file names, making it difficult to recognize what file is opened for each tab.

So, How can I configure vim's tabpage window to have multiple lines rather than just one line?

(If there is another good way to deal with multiple files, welcome, but you should first answer to the main question.)

Comment: I don't know if there's a solution to your main question, but I suspect there isn't -- Vim is, I believe, designed to be used with buffers to manage multiple files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, what you ask is not possible with vim as it is. Adding that behaviour *may* be possible if you play with vim's source code but this is almost certainly a lost cause.

*However,* vim's tabs are not 1-to-1 file proxies and you are wrong in treating them as such. The canonical multiple-buffer management method is to open each file as a buffer (that's how Vim works by default, the buffer *is* the 1-to-1 file proxy you need) and jump from one to another. It's simpler, more solid and infinitely more scalable than tabs (which are a fundamentally broken UX paradigm anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:tabs` List the tab pages and the windows they contain.

For more information :

```
:help :tabs
```

By the way, there is no need to use tab to open multiple files. Vim is based on buffers.

Basically, you can do `vim file1 file2`, each file is open in a buffer. So, you can use `:bn` (buffer next) to switch between buffers.